# Error when trying to deploy my app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I'm using railshoster.de and they don't help me deploying my app.

It is this one: `https://github.com/ClaudiuCreanga/your-priorities`

It works in localhost.

Railshohster.de is using capistrano and passanger.

I get this error when trying to run it: `We're sorry, but something went wrong.`

In `development.log` there is no error.

What did I do:

1) Cloned my app

2) bundle install - worked well

3) rake db:schema:load and rake db:seed also worked well.

My questions are:

Where else can I look for errors?

Should it be any difference in deploying localhost vs online?

Thanks!

Comment: `development.log` for development env you need `production.log`

Comment: Are you trying to launch your app in `development` mode on a production server? If `RAILS_ENV` is set to `production` there, errors will go to the corresponding log file. Check it out.

Comment: @PhilidorGreen @D-side In log folder I only have `development.log` I selected on railshoster the development environment. Can the `production.log` be somewhere else? Even if I switch to production environment, there is no new file in logs folder

Comment: log file created under environment. If you have only `development.log` this mean you run server in development env.

Comment: I suggest you do learn `capistrano`, it makes your deploys really hassle free once you have it set up (which may be a little difficult at first, but there should be enough tutorials around to get you started).

Comment: @Patru Thanks! I'm not a rails developer. I liked that app and I just modified the html&CSS. Can it be that this app (or any app) is made to work only on localhost? Or if it works on localhost it should work online too?

Comment: @Claudiu: If it works on `localhost` it will usually work *if you deploy it correctly*. That is exactly what `capistrano` is doing an excellent job with, it will reliably deploy your application after changes, but you will have to set it up first. Nothing, not even open source software, comes for free nowadays. But I still think it will pay off to learn capistrano if you plan to run a few releases of your changed app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally the issue was with the table migration not being done properly and failing at some point.